# how to disable repeated click in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have div1 and div2,onclick of div1 or div2 'paragraph' will be displayed here,Again onclick of 'paragraph' some alert will come based on div1 or div2 clicked.After that here the problem is if I switch between div1 and and div2 and again click on 'paragraph',repeated alert is coming here.But I dont want to make repeated alert.Can anyone please help me,Below is the code.Thanks in advance

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("p").hide();

     $(".div1").on("click",function(){
    // alert('hi');
     $("p").show();
         $("p").click(function(){
        alert("p inside div1");
    });
    });
     $(".div2").on("click",function(){
      $("p").show();
        $("p").click(function(){
        alert("p inside div2");
    });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
<div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a</div>
<p class="para">paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the event handlers correctly.

As I understand your objective... The `div1` and `div2` click should only change a "reference". And the alert should be made on `p` click.

So just write it like that!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide();

  var alertText;  // A variable to use as a "reference".
  
  $(".div1").one("click",function(){
    $("p").show();
    alertText = "Click on the first div.";
  });

  $(".div2").one("click",function(){
    $("p").show();
    alertText = "Click on the second div.";
  });
  
  $("p").on("click",function(){
    if(alertText!=""){
      alert(alertText);
    }
    alertText="";
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
<div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
<p class="para">paragraph</p>
```

**EDIT**
To have the alert only once, you can use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which binds a handler to be executed only once.

Then on `p` click, alert with the text setted by a `div` handler, then flush the value of that text. The condition to alert only if there is a text setted will make the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but here my objective is to disable repeated click. here alert can be anything like instead of "p inside div1" may be "first one clicked" and  instead of "p inside div2" may be "second one clicked"..I have the same scenario in my project where need to call ajax/api based on click

Comment: So you just want to have ONE click for each `div`?

Comment: yes but again when I switch to other div and click on paragraph it should alert the text  again.

Comment: Okay... So on `div` click, set a text. On `p` click, alert only if there is a text setted. ;) I edited my answer.

Comment: I just saw the Ajax scenario that you posted as an answer... The above edit will work for it too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is toggle a selected class on the nav items and look for that class when you click the paragraph

```js
$('.nav-item').click(function(){
   $('.para').show();
   $('.nav-item.selected').removeClass('selected')
   $(this).addClass('selected')
})

$('.para').click(function(){
   var selected = $('.nav-item.selected a').text()
   console.log('selected is ', selected)
})
```

```css
p.para{display:none}
.selected a{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-item"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
  <div class="nav-item"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
</nav>
<section>
  <p class="para">paragraph</p>      
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div;
  $("p").hide();
  $(".div1").on("click", function() {
    $("p").show();
    div = 'div 1';
  });

  $(".div2").on("click", function() {
    $("p").show();
    div = 'div 2';
  });

  $("p").click(function() {
    alert("p inside " + div);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
<div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
<p class="para">paragraph</p>
```

You missed a angle bracket( `>` ) on a tag. And i think code structure would be like above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but here my objective is to disable repeated click. here alert can be anything like instead of "p inside div1" may be "first one clicked" and  instead of "p inside div2" may be "second one clicked"..I have the same scenario in my project where need to call ajax/api based on click

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var div;
      var count = 0;
      $("p").hide();
      $(".div1").on("click", function() {
        $("p").show();
        div = 'div 1';
        count = 0;
      });

      $(".div2").on("click", function() {
        $("p").show();
        div = 'div 2';
        count = 0;
      });

      $("p").click(function() {
        if( count === 0 ){
            alert("p inside " + div);
        }
        count++;
      });
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
    <div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
    <p class="para">paragraph</p>










    $(document).ready(function() {
      var div;
      var count;
      $("p").hide();
      $(".div1").on("click", function() {
        $("p").show();
        div = 'div 1';
      });

      $(".div2").on("click", function() {
        $("p").show();
        div = 'div 2';
      });

      $("p").click(function() {
        alert("p inside " + div);
      });
    });
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
    <div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
    <p class="para">paragraph</p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div;

  $("p").hide();
  $(".div1").on("click", function() {
    $("p").show();
    div = 'div 1';
  });

  $(".div2").on("click", function() {
    $("p").show();
    div = 'div 2';
  });

  $("p").click(function() {
    alert("p inside " + div);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
<div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
<p class="para">paragraph</p>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div;
  $("p").hide();
  $(".div1").on("click", function() {
    $("p").show();
    div = 'div 1';
  });

  $(".div2").on("click", function() {
    $("p").show();
    div = 'div 2';
  });

  $("p").click(function() {
    alert("p inside " + div);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
<div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
<p class="para">paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be correct when I call the ajax with that scenario

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hide();

  var ajaxuri;  // A variable to use as a "reference".

  $(".div1").on("click",function(){
    $("p").show();
    ajaxuri=0;

  });

  $(".div2").on("click",function(){
    $("p").show();
    ajaxuri=1;

  });

  $("p").on("click",function(){
  alert(ajaxuri);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/bootstrap/onclick/response.json?id="+ajaxuri,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#name1").text(result.critical[0].name);
            $("#value1").text(result.critical[0].value);

            $("#name2").text(result.major[0].name);
            $("#value2").text(result.major[0].value);

            $("#name3").text(result.minor[0].name);
            $("#value3").text(result.minor[0].value);
        }
    });
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1"><a href="#">div1</a></div>
<div class="div2"><a href="#">div2</a></div>
<p class="para">paragraph</p>

</body>
</html>
```